# "Tomato cage" plastic connections -- Design idea

Tags: design, plastic, fastener, connectors

I'm creating on AutoCAD a hydroponic tower garden.

I would like to get some ideas about how to design the connections between the parts required to build a tomato cage.

Here's a bird's eye view of the project:

[image: bird's eye view -- tower garden project]

I'm planning on stacking 6 levels of red circles.

Now... Zooming in, specifically on the tomato cage...

[image: tomato cage -- zooming in]

My question is... What is the best way to connect those parts? Some requirements:

-- Without using any tools 
-- Easy to disconnect 
-- Preferably, no external fasteners. Everything needs to be integrated 
-- Firm connections between the parts... No shaking (vibration) in windy conditions

Thickness: 6.5mm. If necessary, it can be changed. Maybe the red circle needs to be thicker.

I would like to have some suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically a wire product like this would be electro-welded together.

[image]

Your set of criteria is going to be next to impossible to achieve. You envision something that has the properties of a fully welded structure but desire it to be a pile of loose parts.

I believe that your best goal would be to make each level of your gadget an electro-welded assembly that is self sufficient from a structural standpoint. The design should be such that these pieces are able to stack together. At each interface between the levels there would be adjacent horizontal rings that are part of the lower stacked element and the next stacked unit. You could then have the user/installer then tie these rings together using nylon zip-ties of an appropriate size. Dis-assembly is as simple as cutting these ties with a diagonal cutter.

Cross sectional detail of one side. White dots are electro welds.
[image]